# Make all wpf project windows topmost programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, topmost

It is possible to make individual windows topmost in the Visual Studio designer or with code, however is there a way to make every window topmost at once with code?

The issue I have is that just making the main parent window topmost hides any other windows, so obviously I need to make them all topmost, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly** the owner of the window has to be specified when the instance is created.

The following example shows how the new window has the owner set first before it is shown.
`MyWindow _MyWindow = new MyWindow() { Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow };`

NOTE: The window being set as the owner has to be shown already otherwise you might get a `XamlParseException` or `InvalidOperationException`.

**Secondly** you just need to use `_MyWindow.ShowDialog()` to show the window.
This prevents the owner window from moving on top of the owned window even if it is set to topmost *after* the child window is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Set the TopMost property on the MainWindow.

Then when creating any other child Windows/Dialog's pass the MainWindow property into the show dialog method. This sets the child window up as a modal dialog box. This means that it will always appear above the main window.

```
public void ShowModelDialog()
{
  MyDialog d = new MyDialog();

  d.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

[See here for more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: OK thank you,  I will try this out and get back to you if it works for my situation or not.

Comment: OK the code you specified does not work but the theory was correct. I had to specify the owner of the window when I created the instance. Then `ShowDialog()`. Thanks anyway!